# Cant access site intermittently, site not available

Tags: domain-name-system, website, cache

I have a news site I check stuff for regularly..

Once in a while I can't access it completely from my 5 different browsers and even from the command line, nslookup cant resolve, ping and tracert fails.. All not being able to resolve the site name. The problem is specific to this one website.

I am told by the site support person that problem is that its cache on my machine or on ISP and I say that's not true because this site I access it 1-2-3 times a week from one browser only. I only fire up the other ones in times of trouble. And when i have the problem even if i try on my secondary machines i still get the same problems.

When the problem goes away, all works well.
My question is: what's causing the intermittent dns/http problems. I don't believe this is something to do with my machine because the issue disappears without me having done anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

Whose DNS servers are you using? Try using Google's public DNS for a while and see if it makes a difference: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

(More info: http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns)

Answer (score 0):

When the problem occurs, run nslookup specifiying a variety of public DNS servers such as Google's public DNS servers. If they also are unable to resolve the site then the problem is with your DNS hoster. If they are able to resolve the site then the problem is with whichever DNS servers your computers are using.

Answer (score 0):

Not scientific, but you might also want to check out http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ and http://internetpulse.net/.

If you use internetpulse.net, it helps to know which Tier 1 providers are being traversed from end to end. A tracert generally can give you the information you need for this. Sometimes you can find that's there's a peering issue between two providers, that said, it's rare and it's more likely an issue at one of the end points.